# Custom directive validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down as a custom directive. I need form validation on it so i used this code:

```
autoQuoteApp.directive('dropdown', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { 
        listData:'=',
        selectedOption: "="
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="selectedOption" name="drop" required ng-options="list.id as list.value for list in listData"></select>',
    };
});
```

the html code is:

```
<div class="input-align">
    <dropdown selected-option='driverInfo.primaryVehicle' list-data='primaryVehicles'></dropdown>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.drop.$error.required">
        Required!   
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem i am facing is that i have multiple drop downs in a single page and the validation is working for just one.

As soon as i select value for the first one the **'Required'** text is removed for all but i need it to be ther till i select value for that particular drop down.

Comment: If you use a module like this you won't need to do any special work validation will just appear for all the elements http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/

Answer (score 0):

For each directive that you have created, keep a separate name

like "drop1"

```
<div class="input-align">
<dropdown name="drop1" selected-option='driverInfo.primaryVehicle' list-data='primaryVehicles'></dropdown>
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.drop1.$error.required">
    Required!   
</span>
```

For other drop down keep different name "drop2"

```
<div class="input-align">
<dropdown name="drop2" selected-option='driverInfo.primaryVehicle' list-data='primaryVehicles'></dropdown>
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.drop2.$error.required">
    Required!   
</span>
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I also tried to pass the name to the directive and use it but even that doesn't seem to work.  Is there any changes that needs to be made to the isolated driective